# How to address reviewer's suggestion for new experiments, the results of which have been communicated elsewhere?

Tags: publications

I received review comments on a manuscript submitted about 6 months back. One of the reviewers suggested performing a few new experiments. But the same experiments were performed recently and the results have already been communicated elsewhere for possible consideration. How should I address the comment?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should ask the editor. They may  decide to go ahead and publish your paper, or want to wait for the results of the new experiments to appear. In either case you should revise the paper to discuss the new experiments.

Comment: I have discussed the findings of the new results in the new manuscript. I am worried that discussing the same in this manuscript will amount to self-plagiarism.

Comment: It's not self plagiarism if it's cited/acknowledged; That's independent of whether or not the editor allows it..

Answer (score 1):

I think @EthanBolker's suggestion is spot on: ask the editor. Additionally, if your field is permissive of preprints, you may be able to submit and cite a preprint of the work you've already submitted for review - check the policies of the journal you've already submitted to. Depending on the delays for review on each paper you may be able to update the citation before publishing or it may remain with the preprint, either is fine.

Comment: The journal does not permit citing articles under review.

Comment: @196104002 Including preprints? The preprint is not really under review. What is your field?

Comment: My field is Civil Engineering. What if I cite the preprint/manuscript under review and that gets rejected?

Comment: @196104002 Preprints can't really be rejected.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what is a preprint?

Comment: @196104002 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint

Comment: Thanks. Both journals do not allow preprints.